# Re-sequence column data to fill in gaps left after row deletion?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to re-sequence the content of a column after deletions leave a missing value.

The troubles..
1 - the values are not unique, but can repeat any number of times, so SORT and ROW_NUMBER won't work.
2 - the values are not sequential in presentation, they can appear in any order, but must always -as a whole- progress from 1 to the maximum value without any gaps.

A visual of what I am trying to accomplish..
**ID, Case, Othercols**

> 1, 1, data
>   2, 3, data
>   6, 5, data
>   8, 3, data

I need to create a procedure to find the missing values in Case and pull all higher values down to fill in the gaps.

**ID, Case, OtherCols**

> 1, 1, data
>   2, 2, data
>   6, 3, data
>   8, 2, data

I know there are better ways to resolve the issue than this, but the database is part of a server so I cannot change how it operates, only the content, and even that only at specific times.

I am only able to remove the 'failed' data and re-sequence (so far by hand) to get the software to take the result as valid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can resequence the values using variables:

```
select case, (@rn := @rn + 1) as newval
from (select distinct case from table t order by case) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars;
```

With this as a lookup table, you can then renumber the values:

```
update table t join
       (select case, (@rn := @rn + 1) as newval
        from (select distinct case from table t order by case) t cross join
             (select @rn := 0) vars
       ) tt
       on t.case = tt.case
    set t.case = tt.newval;
```

Note:  this uses `case` as a column name even though that is not allowed in MySQL.

Comment: I hadn't considered handling it in two processes like this.
This works perfectly for the task.

Thank you!